# Self reference in $.fn jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway that i can refer to the "mouseWheelEvent" property from the "beforeSlide" method?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$(".main").hide();
var des = false;
var scorll = false;
var slider = $.fn.fsvs({
    speed : 1000,
    bodyID : 'fsvs-body',
    selector : '> .slide',
    mouseSwipeDisance : 40,
    afterSlide : function(){},
    beforeSlide : () => {
        if($("#slide-3").hasClass("active-slide") && !des){
            $('#fsvs-body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
                if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
                    console.log("up");
                }
                else{ 
                    $(".main").fadeIn(200, function(){
                        $("html").addClass("des");

                        $("#fsvs-body").addClass("des");
                        des = true;
                        scorll = false;
                        $('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: 200
                        }, 200);
                        console.log(scorll);       
                    });
                }
                $('#fsvs-body').unbind('mousewheel');
            });
        }
    },
    endSlide : function(){},
    mouseWheelEvents : scorll,
    mouseWheelDelay : false,
    scrollableArea : 'scrollable',
    mouseDragEvents : true,
    touchEvents : true,
    arrowKeyEvents : true,
    pagination : false,
    nthClasses : false,
    detectHash : true,
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    if(des){
        if($(document).scrollTop() == 0){
            $(".main").fadeOut(200, function(){
                $("html").removeClass("des");
                $("#fsvs-body").removeClass("des");
                des = false;
                console.log(scorll);

            }); 
        }
    }
});
```

});

I want to toggle the mouseWheelEvent in beforeSlide and in $(window).scroll as i want the mouse wheel to be true in $(window).scroll and be false in beforeSlide.

Comment: Depends on what `fsvs` does. What is it?

Comment: It's a class that the plugin uses

Comment: A class? Why would it be a method on the jQuery prototype then?

Comment: Sorry, I mean it's a css class name :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, but if you create the plugin the usual way, not just as an object literal, and don't use an arrow function, you could probably get the `mouseWheelEvents` method as an option instead, and then you'd have to debounce the  `scroll` event and a set a boolean that timeouts after some time etc?

Comment: Actually i'm not the one who created this plugin but i want a way to refer to the mouseWheelEvents from the beforSlide function and from outside the object.